# Having trouble initializing variable

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to initialize a variable in a view controller before that view controller takes over the view, and it seems no matter how I try to initialize it, it doesn't work and the software runs as if the value is the default value.  Part of the problem seems to be the view that contains the variable in question is nil when I try to set the variable's value.  I don't know why this is.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!  Here is my code:

```
override func setStartPosition()
{
    if sessionNameIndex != nil
    {
        if let curSession = ShareData.sharedInstance.sessionDataObjectContainer[sessionNames[sessionNameIndex]]
        {
            initialValue = YesNo(rawValue: (curSession.currentValue))

            if mySessionDisplay == nil
            {
                mySessionDisplay = SessionDisplayView(frame: self.view.frame)
                if mySessionDisplay == nil
                {
                    var shouldneverbehere = 0  //Always goes here!
                }
                else
                {
                    mySessionDisplay.onView(index: 2, sessionName: sessionNames[sessionNameIndex])
                    mySessionDisplay.curScene.setStartPosition(newValue: val!)
                }

            }



        }
    }
}
```

This function gets called in the following code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{

    if let destination = segue.destination as? SessionDisplayViewControllerTwo
    {
        if let myNames = sender as? [String]
        {
            destination.sessionNames = myNames
            destination.sessionNameIndex = 1
            destination.setStartPosition()
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need more information.  Once again, thanks for your consideration of this matter.

Comment: Is `mySessionDisplay` an IBOutlet connection?

Comment: I find it hard to read your code - a guard statement plus following if statements with a curly bracket on the same line is more to my style - but obviously your issue is mySessionDisplay is *still* nil in the second if. But in your prepare(segue:) call I'm looking at SessionDisplayViewControllerTwo? That's not what you are checking in your nested ifs. Could you provide more code to explain this?

Comment: please add exactly which variables are nil and are the problematic ones

Comment: you should move your calculating code into your controller and call there the `setStartPosition` most in viewDidLoad you can setup your viewcontroller and not in a seque

Comment: in a seque you should only assign values

Comment: @ebby94 Yes mySessionDisplay is an IBOutlet connection.  Specifically it's a custom UIView.

Comment: @dfd I don't understand your comment  The first section of code is within SessionDisplayViewControllerTwo.  The second section of code is where this function gets called- from another class called SessionDisplayViewControllerOne.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: @muescha The problem is assigning a variable within mySessionDisplay.  No matter how I try to assign a value to the variable within mySessionDisplay- and I have tried other ways- it won't receive a value.  I've tried doing it within viewDidLoad, and that won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

A view controller's views have not yet been loaded in `prepareForSegue`. As @muescha suggests in his comment, you should set properties in `prepareForSegue`, and then wait for `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` before you try to install them in your views. I'm not sure why your attempt to manually create your `SessionDisplayView` is failing, but you should not be trying to create views in `prepareForSegue` in any case, so the solution is "Don't do that."

Comment: The problem is, no matter how I try to set the variable within the view mySessionDisplay, it won't receive a value.  I'm not sure how to make this happen- and while my code as presented may not be the way it should be done, I've tried other ways that have failed as well.

Comment: The approach you posted is certainly wrong. You pass values in prepareForSegue, and then install them in your views in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear. (In viewDidLoad your views are loaded but their layout isn't final.) Edit your question to show code that works that way, but fails, and explain in detail what it's doing wrong.

Comment: Okay, but I solved the problem I was trying to solve on my own.  Thank you for your input.  It turns out there were two issues- one swift does not convert raw integers into an enumeration correctly- at least as best as I can tell, it was converting them incorrectly.  Two, I somehow thought that the setStartPosition function of the custom skscene class was happening before the init function was called.  It occurs after, and so I needed to change the position of the graphic manually in the setStartPosition function.  Long story short, the problem I was trying to solve has been solved.